# How to solve PowerBI OLE DB or ODBC error

Tags: powerbi

[image]

Hi everyone,

I have a dashboard in PowerBI. All the tables are in direct query mode connected to my data warehouse. The reason I'm using direct query is because the tables are too large which are not suitable to use import mode.

I encounter the error as shown in the screenshot above one day (previously works fine). I saw a lot of people facing the same issue, and the main reason is due to the query that PowerBI formed to call the data from data warehouse is too complicated. However, when I use another device to open the dashboard in PowerBI desktop, it works fine. I have no idea on why it behave like this. If the query is too complicated, shouldn't it behave the same regardless of which devices? Please advice on how can I solve this error. Any advice or help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *"I'm using direct query is because the tables are too large which are not suitable to use import mode."* - i think you need to include the offending expression and the target database in the question. i hope [tag:powerbi] experts can start from there.